# How to render only selective elements from a Parent Component to child ? ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

As the title says,I'm looking for a way to render only selective components from from the parent to a child.For instance,

Let me Parent Component be :

```
export default class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="signupWrapper">
                <h2>Sign up</h2>
                <p>Already have a account?
                    <Link to="/login"> click here to Sign In</Link>
                </p> 
         ) 
     }
}

//Now,let's import the parent to a child,


import Signup from '/pathtoparent'
export default class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                 <Signup/>
            </div>
         )
    }
}
```

My question is : What to do if I don't want the p OR h2 tag from the parent into my child ? I could render it conditionally but is there an alternative to simply not render the selective tags from the parent ?

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: I did.Thank you.

Comment: Anyways I think you might be confusing parent with child. You are supposed to use child in the parent, not parent inside your child.

Comment: Just formatted your code. Please, spend some time doing this because it was pretty unreadable.

Comment: @Kinduser Either ways,the question still remains the same : How do I render only selective elements from the imported component ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `prop` from your parent to the child and then add a conditional render in your child component

So your parent will look like this

```
import Signup from '/pathtoparent'
export default class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div className="container">
               <Signup renderh2={condition_true_or_false} renderP={condition_true_or_false}/>
          </div>
       )
  }
}
```

While your child will look like

```
export default class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="signupWrapper">
                {this.props.renderh2 && <h2>Sign up</h2>}
                {this.props.renderP && <p>Already have a account?
                    <Link to="/login"> click here to Sign In</Link>
                </p> } 
         ) 
     }
}
```